# Weak convergence of measures on the unit sphere $S^2$.

Tags: measure-theory, distribution-theory, weak-convergence, spheres

Let $(x_i,y_i) \in S^{\mathbb{N}} \times S^\mathbb{N}$ where $S$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Assume the following result of weak convergence for measures :

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{x_i,y_i} \underset{N \rightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow} f(x,y) dx dy$$
which means that for any continous function $\varphi \in C^0(S^2)$, we have :

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \varphi(x_i,y_i) \underset{N \rightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_{S^2} \varphi(x,y) f(x,y) dx dy.$$
We ask that $f$ is in $W^{1,1}(S^2)$ (for exemple, any other kind of regularity would do) so that everything is well defined. **Knowing this, I would like to find a measure $\mu_N$ such that :**

$$\mu_N \underset{N \rightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow} \partial_n f(x,y) dx dy$$
where $n$ is the extern normal on $S^2$. More exactly, I want that, for any suitable test functions $\varphi \in C^0(S^2)$,

$$\int_{S^2} \varphi d\mu_N \underset{N \rightarrow + \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int_{S^2} \varphi(x,y) \partial_n f(x,y) dx dy.$$

My guess was the following :

$$\mu_N=-\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \delta'_{x_i,y_i} \cdot n(x_i,y_i),$$
where $\delta'_{x_i,y_i}$ is the distribution such that $\langle \delta'_{x_i,y_i}| \varphi \rangle := \nabla \varphi(x_i,y_i)$ for any $\varphi \in D(S^2)$. However, it is just an intuition using the definition of integration by parts through distribution, and I'm not even sure this is well defined since my $\mu_N$ need to be applied with function at least $C^1$, which is not the case for the weak convergence of measures.

Any help or advice are welcome.